# Is it sinful to give non vegetarian food to a carnivore pet for the owner?

Tags: dharma-shastras, non-vegetarian, natya-shastra

It is part of the nature of that animal, they don't have option like humans.
So should this be sinful for someone to feed them ? Please guide

Comment: First of all it is sin to even have pets.

Comment: @Carmensandiego please show reference 

Comment: See this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20722/18974

Comment: As a practice, I have mostly seen ppl feeding veg food to pets or street animals. Maybe to keep their temperament cool. Not sure about what shastra says about this

Comment: Also pls note feeding or taking care of animals is not the same as keeping them as pets. The former is encouraged while later is a sin.

Comment: As a matter of biology, cats, big and small, are the world's only true carnivores (as opposed to herbivores and omnivores) - they cannot process plant proteins. All cats require animal flesh to live.

Comment: Does the scriptures tell us, why is it a sin to keep pets?